# I create both nginx and app service in k8s on port 80, how can I get to the app service

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Recently I am learning kubernetes.
I made a k8s cluster and deployed nginx and my app service on it, both nginx and the app service were exposed on port 80, I can only get to nginx default landing page when I try to access the external IP address on port 80, am I doing something wrong and how can I fix that, need help 
I deploy nginx with this commands

```
kubectl create deployment nginx --image=nginx:1.21.1
kubectl expose deployment nginx --external-ip=$MASTER_IP --port=80 --target-port=80
```

This is yam file for my service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: node
  labels:
    app: node
    tier: backend
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 3000
  # Replace with the IP of your minikube node / master node
  externalIPs:
    - xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
  selector:
    app: node
    tier: backend
```

Comment: Its not clear from the above as to how the nginx service and the node service are connected. The selector in the service yaml is mentioned as node and nginx's name is not node.
The LoadBalancer is aware only of the pods named node and not the pod that was created by nginx deployment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your first command created the deployment and POD
2. Your second command exposed the deployment on PORT 80.

When you accessed the page on external-ip:port, the request went to pod via the service created at #2. Default page implies that web server is successfully installed and woking.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, while what I want is go directly to the services landing page, if it behaves as expected according to my configs, then how can I access my services page, and the targetPort is 3000, why it doesn't go to the port 3000, I am a little bit confused about that too.

Comment: Is the target port 3000 configured on the pods with selector app: node | tier: backend ?

The service name is node where as the nginx will be with app : nginx.


```
k expose deploy test --external-ip=00.00.00.00 --port=80 --target-port=80 --dry-run=client -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
**   app: test**
  name: test
spec:
  externalIPs:
  - 00.00.00.00
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  selector:
    app: test
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: Problem solved finally, thanks. Turned out k8s is harder than I thought 